# Why can't there be a son without a spouse? (Verse 6:101)

Tags: quran, tafseer

> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. **How could He have a
> son when He does not have a companion** [i.e., wife] and He created
> all things? And He is, of all things, Knowing. ([6] Al-An'am : 101)

The Quran says that the prophet Isa was born without a father. So why does this verse say that without a wife, there can be no son?

Answer (score 3):

Here, Allah shows the foolishness of the Christian use of the word "son."

The very definition of the word "son" or "daughter" has to do with a biological process (unless for adopted sons, which is not what they claim Jesus is).

When there is no such biological process, it does not make sense to call something a "son." Rather, you would call that thing a "creation." If someone creates something not through the biological process, that is a creation.

That is why Allah says ⟪How could He have a son when He does not have a companion [i.e., wife] and He created all things?⟫ (6:101) How can you claim Allah has a son when there is no wife involved (i.e. there is no biological process) and we call everything else that comes without a biological process by Allah's power and will a creation?

As for Jesus (AS) being born without a father, that is irrelevant. He is only called the son of Maryam (AS) because she gave birth to him with the well-known biological process. Mothers don't need a father to be related to their sons because the biological process that relates them to their son is independent of a father (i.e. giving birth and carrying the baby in their womb).

As for fathers, their biological process is intimately related to mothers. So, it is impossible (on a conceptual level) for a father to have a son without a mother but a mother can have a son without a father because she gives birth.

The other possibility is that Christians are using the word "son" to mean "adopted son" which they deny. Another possibility is they invented an entirely new definition of the word son then used it, but that makes no sense to do. Why would you use the word "son" specifically which implies a biological process if you could just choose a new word?