# Can Allah (the Holy) have a son without a partner?

Tags: tafseer

> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a
> son when He does not have a companion [i.e., wife] and He created all
> things? And He is, of all things, Knowing. ([6] Al-An'am : 101)

How can we understand this verse, because we know that Allah can do anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't there be a son without a spouse? (Verse 6:101)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80310/why-cant-there-be-a-son-without-a-spouse-verse-6101)

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate.

Comment: I see some confusion here based on words and there meanings. Is a **son** a procreation in HIS image, or a biological result of sexual intercourse? Many languages, many interpretations. If you stick to the first one, then we all are sons and daughters of Allah.

Answer (score 1):

You can read answer to related question here [Why can't there be a son without a spouse? (Verse 6:101)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80310/why-cant-there-be-a-son-without-a-spouse-verse-6101)

In addition, you said "Therefore, in order to have a son and Allah, it is not necessary to have a partner, which contradicts verse 6:101. "

Of course, Allah can create anything without any parent or only one parent.

> Indeed, the example of Jesus in the sight of Allah is like that of
> Adam. He created him from dust, then said to him, “Be!” And he was! [Quran 3:59](https://quran.com/en/ali-imran/59)

Quran 6:101 is negating the idea of some people thinking Allah as similar to themselves, like having real son. So it is asked, how can he have real son, when he don't have a partner or spouse.

In case of Adam, there is no mother or father. So Allah can create without any parent or with one parent. But some people try to equate Allah with created beings and attribute one of his creation to be his real son, for example, they say Jesus is his real son. This idea of connecting his creation to Allah is negated in this verse logically, the question of real son do not arise, as he is far above to what is being attributed to him, one reason being he do not have a spouse which **usual** sexual reproduction require.

Comment: I have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Claim is equivalent to God cannot take a son without a wife according to Quran. First of all, the verses have no statement “cannot”. God is omnipotent and capable of doing any thing He wills. “Cannot” cannot be applied to God by definition. Thus if God wished He could have had a son. But He didnt wished it. This is the translation of 39:4 as follows

**Quran 39:4 If Allah had intended to take a son, He could have chosen from what He creates whatever He willed. Exalted is He; He is Allah, the One, the Prevailing.**

THUS, the meaning in 39:4 is God never did take a son because He had not willed it.

The verse 6:101 does not state any relation between having son and having mate although this could be interpreted. Unfortunately majority of translations put such an implication by adding additional word **when** instead of **And**. Original verse only says God has no son, and has no companion, etc. Also, this verse respond to those who think that Jesus is the begotten son. God simplly implies this is a biological process of human beings that does not fit to The Originator of Everything. Importantly there is no rule stated in the verse that having son requires having mate. Here is the translation

**Quran(6:101) Originator of the heavens and the earth, How does He get a son? And He has no companion. And He created everything. And He is Ever-Knowing of everything?**

Similar verse is as follows

**Quran 17:111 and say: “Praise be to Allah, Who has not taken a son. And He has no partner in (His) Dominion. And He needs no protector out of dependence. And magnify Him with all magnificence.**

Comment: I still think the translation is correct. Since a similar construction is used in verses 2:247, 19:8. Are there indications from reputable imams that the word "wow" in the verse translates as "and"?

Comment: Unfortunately, translators hardly follow word by word translations. The usage of "And" is generic in Quran. Usually it is used to explain the preceeding sentence or creates a common theme between terms. Yes there are constructions [(impossibility of something) AND reason] But there are also contructions like [example1 AND example2] where examples shares a common theme (e.g. God has no human-like relation). You can also consider both constructions are valid. Remember that the verse is response to the claim Jesus is the begothen Son. This is the reason that it is interpreted in construction-1.

Answer (score 0):

The claim is equivalent to **"God has no son due to having no wife** according to the verse". Here is the original verse that there is no such claim.

**Quran(6:101) Originator of the heavens and the earth, How does He get a son? And He has no companion. And He created everything. And He is Ever-Knowing of everything?**

The first sentence infer that The Originator of the heavens and earth (God) has no son. This fact is trasmitted to the next due to **"And"** operator. Consequently, **Fact1: "God has no son"**, **Fact2: "God has no companion"** holds at the same time. It is the interpretation part to create a link between the two facts. Although, there is no problem in doing so, it is not the word of God but must be regarded as an interpretation.

Quran actually claims that God has no son as a concept, not conceivable for The Originator of the Heavens and Earth, irrilevant to the fact that God has no companion (Fact2). The following verses well establish that **Fact1** holds irrilevant to **Fact2**.

**Quran 10:68** They have said, "Allah has taken a son." Exalted is He; He is the [one] Free of need. To Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and whatever is in the earth. You have no authority for this [claim]. Do you say about Allah that which you do not know?

**Quran 2:116** They say, "Allah has taken a son." Exalted is He! Rather, to Him belongs whatever is in the heavens and the earth. All are devoutly obedient to Him

**Quran 17:111** and say: “Praise be to Allah, Who has not taken a son. And He has no partner in (His) Dominion. And He needs no protector out of dependence. And magnify Him with all magnificence.

**Quran 19:90-93** ...they attribute to the Most Merciful a son. And it is not appropriate for the Most Merciful that He should take a son.There is no one in the heavens and earth but that he comes to the Most Merciful as a servant.

Quran generally claim that any human like relation cannot be attributed to God, such as Son, Daughter and Companion. Thus, it is normal to refer to the human like relations and critisize them in the same verse. For example, Quran 16:57 "And they attribute daughters to Allah - exalted is He..."

**Summary**

Quran(6:101):   **Fact1 AND Fact2**

Quran(10:68):   **Fact1**

Quran (2:116):  **Fact1**

**.....**

**Fact1 can be inferred independent of Fact2**.